# Facing Issue during mobile Testing in Eclipse using appium

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, appium

I am just trying to do automation testing on mobile apps but facing the below Issues:

1. Only `ES-File-Explorer-Pro-1.1.2-Mod.apk` app is getting installed with the below code but others are failing

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

   File appDir=new File("Drivers");
   File app=new File(appDir, "ES-File-Explorer-Pro-1.1.2-Mod.apk");

   DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
   cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
   cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Emulator");

   cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
   WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
   ```
2. With others apps, seeing the below error

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/6811571d7ee802f0b73db5e59deef57a.apk

   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
   Command duration or timeout: 39.19 seconds
   ```

Also, Please let me any silly mistakes if I have in my code as I am new to this.

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is not the complete code to launch the app in mobile. Can you post the complete DesiredCapabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Test");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,60);
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
driver =  new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
return driver;
}
@Test
public void Test() {
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit")).click();
}
```

Try to return driver.